# Why 'bundle install' need these files to be pre-installed?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle

Here's what I tried:

1. `gem install testgen` 
    
   success
2. `gem install bundle`
   success
3. go to project root created using testgen
4. `bundle install` this failed and asked to install `gem install i18n -v '0.6.11'`
    So I added it in gemfile this way `gem 'i18n', '>=0.6.11'` and tried `bundle install` again but it gave same error again. So I had to install it manually without using `bundle install`
5. Once this is completed it asked for many other files.

Question is: If I had to install gems manually one by one what's the use of `bundle install` then?

 and 
Why it was not installing the required `gem` when it is specified in `Gemfile`?

Answer (score 0):

The command `bundle install` goes through every gem in the Gemfile and installs it, along with all dependencies.

An error like yours means that one of the gems, or one of its dependencies, failed to install. The Gemfile is already referencing the failing gem; you don't need to reference it again. Instead, try it from the command line:

```
gem install i18n -v '0.6.11'
```

This might fail, but the error will be more useful. This process isn't 'installing gems manually', it is solving problems your computer is raising with certain pieces of software. Bundler can't work through every problem on every kind of machine on its own.

Check out http://bundler.io/, it has some great docs that should help clarify.

Comment: No, I have never had your specific error. This is how you work through any error raised during a bundle install.